# Best way to use list comprehension to create a constant dict of labels and abbreviations dependent upon the number of entries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not as new to Python but I struggle quite a lot with list comprehension, I cannot seem to wrap my head around it. I am learning but would not mind advice on how to solve something in my programme I am writing in an optimal fashion. I have a constant list of labels and corresponding list of abbreviations that the user sets from the command line (or reverts to hardcoded defaults from another `.py` file) and then remains constant throughout the run.

However, I do not know how to write the list comprehension to include a variable amount of inputs without hard coding or using a `for` loop. For example:

```
ALPHA = ['alpha', 'beta', 'zeta']
A     = ['a', 'b', 'z']

A_DICT = {'1': {'label': ALPHA[0], 'abbrev': A[0]},
          '2': {'label': ALPHA[1], 'abbrev': A[1]},
          '3': {'label': ALPHA[2], 'abbrev': A[2]}}
```

How can I create `A_DICT` using list comprehension if this indeed the best the way to create the dict please? The number of entries in `ALPHA` and `A` can change depending on user input. I am sorry if this is low quality/duplicate, I am trying to get my head around list comprehension but it does not quite sink in whereas other aspects of Python do with little issue.

Comment: To create a dict, you use a dict comprehension, not a list comprehension. Both are just fancy for loops, so if you are having difficulty understanding them, then just write a regular for loop. Eventually you will see the similarities and start adopting comprehensions where they are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you could use  python builtin [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), to iterate over two iterables at once.

If you need those numbers as keys in the final dict (`'1', '2', '3'`), you wrap the whole zip generator in `enumerate`.

```py
A_DICT = {str(i): {'label': l, 'abbrev': a} for i, (l, a) in enumerate(zip(ALPHA, A))}
```

Another option, assuming the lists are of equal length, it may be simpler to solely produce the index.

```py
A_DICT = {str(i): {'label': ALPHA[i], 'abbrev': A[i]} for i in range(len(ALPHA))}
```

However, I have doubts about the data structure here in general, though I don't fully understand your specific application. If you always know the keys in each individual dict ('label', and 'abbrev') why not just make a dict that is callable by label to get the abbrev (or the other way around)?

```py
SOME_DICT = {label: abbrev for label, abbrev in zip(ALPHA, A)}

# {'alpha': 'a', 'beta': 'b', 'zeta': 'z'}
```

Edit: As pointed out in comments, above way is same as:

```py
SOME_DICT = dict(zip(ALPHA, A))
```

Comment: In this specific case I do need the numbers, I know how to create `key, val` dicts using list comprehension but not encountered needing the number prior before hence the question! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with dictionary comprehension.

With an assumption that `ALPHA` and `A` are equal length.

```
In [1]: {
     ...:     str(index): {"label": item, "abbrev": A[index]}
     ...:     for index, item in enumerate(ALPHA, start=1)
     ...: }
Out[1]: 
{'1': {'label': 'alpha', 'abbrev': 'a'},
 '2': {'label': 'beta', 'abbrev': 'b'},
 '3': {'label': 'zeta', 'abbrev': 'z'}}
```